# How to make tabbed group with nested <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML that is dynamically generated, the structure essentially looks like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>Class #1
        <ul>
            <li>Joe</li>
            <li>Fred</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Class #2
        <ul>
            <li>Sally</li>
            <li>Bob</li>
            <li>Eve</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create an interface where Class #1 and Class #2 are tabs that reveal their nested `<ul>` of students.

Comment: Sounds great; what have you tried?

Comment: do you mean tabs like jquery ui tabs? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: So you basically just want a list with class #1, class #2. And have the rest nested until you hover over it or something. You are not being clear enough.

Comment: @NickySmits clicking a classroom tab should show the student list.

Comment: @j08691 jQuery UI tabs, but it's the nesting of tags that is messing with my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an onclick action to every list item (with the class number). That action should change the css style from the items below from:

```
display:block;
```

to:

```
display:inherit
```

and vice versa.

**Lets get one thing clear. You have to do some of the work on your own, we are not your own personal monkeys ;)**

Answer (score 1):

I'd use jQueryUI for tabs. See here:

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic implementation of the same using jQuery:

HTML Code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tabs">List1
        <ul class="tabContent"><li>...</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs">List2
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('ul li.tabs:first-child ul.tabContent').show();

$('li.tabs').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.tabContent').show();
    $(this).siblings().find('ul.tabContent').hide();
});
```

CSS Code:

```
ul li.tabs{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabConten{ 
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps.